# What games were released for the PS2 in China during the Console Ban? (if any)

Tags: ps2, gaming-history

[This Kotaku article from 2013](https://kotaku.com/the-short-life-of-the-ps2-in-china-1425748348) mentions that:

> The PS2 didn't make its original launch date. Instead, Sony waited till 2004 to launch the PS2 in China. Even then, there were issues with game releases, which also required government approval. **In total, ten games were released for the PS2 in China**—the PS2 was also launched in Hong Kong and Taiwan at around the same time, but with over 300 titles.

What are those 10 games released in China? If any were released at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a quick search and I was able to find the following 17 games with a P**S**2 **C**opyrighted **C**hinese Relea**S**e [product code](https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/Productcode#Physical):

- Ape Escape 2 - SCCS 40001
- Devil May Cry 2 - SCCS 40002 (Disc 1)/SCCS 40003 (Disc 2)
- XIGO: Zuihou de Touzi (Bombastic) - SCCS 40004
- Ico - SCCS 40005
- Shin Sangoku Musou (Dynasty Warriors) - SCCS 40006
- Arc the Lad: Seirei no Tasogare (Arc the Lad: Twilight of the Spirits) - SCCS 40007
- Dragon Ball Z 2 - SCCS-40009
- Super Puzzle Bobble 2 (Super Bust-A-Move 2) - SCCS 40010
- Armored Core 2: Another Age - SCCS 40011
- World Soccer Winning Eleven 7: International - SCCS 40014
- Viorate no Atelier: Gramnad no Renkinjutsushi 2 - SCCS 40015
- Ape Escape: Pumped & Primed - SCCS 40016
- EyeToy: Play - SCCS 40017
- EyeToy: Saru EyeToy: Oosawagi! Ukkiuki Game Tenkomori!! (EyeToy: Monkey Mania) - SCCS 40018
- Formula One 04 - SCCS 40019
- World Soccer Winning Eleven 8: Asia Championship - SCCS 40022
- Gran Turismo 4 - SCCS 60002